# Why the following codes are receiving referenced before assignment errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Many threads were there offering solutions but there was a case by case scenario.

I assigned the text for string_1_attack in 52,53,61,62,70 and 71 lines of my code. But later when I mentioned string_1_attack in the 87th line of my code, I found the following error--UnboundLocalError: local variable 'string_1_attack' referenced before assignment.

Here's my code:

```py
        # Consider type advantage
        version = ['Fire', 'Water', 'Grass']
        for i, k in enumerate (version):
            if self.types == k:
                # both are same type
                if Pokemon2.types == k:
                    string_1_attack = 'Its not very effective...'
                    string_2_attack = 'Its not very effective...'

                # Pokemon2 is strong
                if Pokemon2.types == version[(i+1)%3]:
                    Pokemon2.attack *=2
                    Pokemon2.defense *=2
                    self.attack /=2
                    self.defense /=2
                    string_1_attack = 'Its not very effective...'
                    string_2_attack = 'Its super effective!'

                # Pokemon2 is weak
                if Pokemon2.types == version[(i+2)%3]:
                    self.attack *=2
                    self.defense *=2
                    Pokemon2.attack /=2
                    Pokemon2.defense /=2
                    string_1_attack = 'Its super effective!'
                    string_2_attack = 'Its not very effective...'



            # Consider while pokemon still have health
            while (self.bars > 0) and (Pokemon2.bars > 0):
                # Print the health of each pokemon
                print(f"\n{self.name}\t\tHLTH\t{self.health}")
                print(f"\n{Pokemon2.name}\t\tHLTH\t{Pokemon2.health}\n")

                print(f"Go {self.name}!")
                for i, x in enumerate(self.moves):
                    print(f"{i+1}.", x)
                index = int(input('Pick a move:  '))
                delay_print(f"{self.name} used {self.moves[index-1]}!")
                time.sleep(1)
                delay_print(string_1_attack)

                # Determine damage
                Pokemon2.bars -= self.attack
                Pokemon2.health = ""

                # Add back bars plus defense boost
                for j in range(int(Pokemon2.bars+.1*Pokemon2.defense)):
                    Pokemon2.health += "="

                time.sleep(1)
                print(f"\n{self.name}\t\tHLTH\t{self.health}")
                print(f"\n{Pokemon2.name}\t\tHLTH\t{Pokemon2.health}\n")
                time.sleep(.5)

                # Check to see if pokemon fainted
                if Pokemon2.bars <=0:
                    delay_print("\n..." + Pokemon2.name + 'fainted.')
                    break

                # Pokemon2s turn

                print(f"Go {Pokemon2.name}!")
                for i, x in enumerate(Pokemon2.moves):
                    print(f"{i+1}.", x)
                index = int(input('Pick a move:  '))
                delay_print(f"{Pokemon2.name} used {Pokemon2.moves[index-1]}!")
                time.sleep(1)
                delay_print(string_2_attack)

                # Determine damage
                self.bars -= Pokemon2.attack
                self.health = ""

                # Add back bars plus defense boost
                for j in range(int(self.bars+.1*self.defense)):
                    self.health += "="

                time.sleep(1)
                print(f"\n{self.name}\t\tHLTH\t{self.health}")
                print(f"\n{Pokemon2.name}\t\tHLTH\t{Pokemon2.health}\n")
                time.sleep(.5)

                # Check to see if pokemon fainted
                if self.bars <=0:
                    delay_print("\n..." + self.name + 'fainted.')
                    break
            money = random.choice(5000)
            delay_print(f"\n Opponent paid you ${money}.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create Pokemon
    Victini = Pokemon('Victini', 'Fire', ['V Flame', 'Victory Star', 'Fire Spin', 'Ember'], {'ATTACK':9, 'DEFENSE':12})
    Kyogre = Pokemon('Kyogre', 'Water', ['Hydro Pump', 'Waterfall', 'Aqua Tail', 'Surf'], {'ATTACK':11, 'DEFENSE': 13})
    Celebi = Pokemon('Celebi','Grass', ['Solar Beam', 'Solar Blade', 'Magical Leaf', 'Leaf Storm'], {'ATTACK': 13, 'DEFENSE':13})

    Entei = Pokemon('Entei', 'Fire', ['Ember', 'Sacred Fire', 'Lava Plume', 'Fire Spin'], {'ATTACK':10, 'DEFENSE':10})
    Keldeo = Pokemon('Keldeo', 'Water', ['Aqua Jet', 'Aqua Tail', 'Bubble Beam', 'Hydro Pump'], {'ATTACK':9, 'DEFENSE': 10})
    Shyamin = Pokemon('Shyamin', 'Grass', ['Energy Ball', 'Leech Seed', 'Bullet Seed', 'Solar Beam'], {'ATTACK':9, 'DEFENSE':9})

    Hoopa = Pokemon('Hoopa', 'Fire', ['Ember', 'Sacred Fire', 'Fire Wheel', 'Flamethrower'], {'ATTACK':11, 'DEFENSE':11})
    Suicune = Pokemon('Suicune', 'Water', ['Hydro Pump', 'Waterfall', 'Aqua Jet', 'Surf'], {'ATTACK':10, 'DEFENSE':10})
    Rayquaza = Pokemon('Rayquaza', 'Grass', ['Solar Beam', 'Destructive leaf blade', 'Air cutter', 'Gates of Hell'], {'ATTACK':14, 'DEFENSE':13})

    Rayquaza.fight(Hoopa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably none of these triple-if statments run. Verifiy that at least one of their conditions are true. To avoid the exception, define `string_1_attack` before the `if`s:

```py
...
for i, k in enumerate (version):
    if self.types == k:
        string_1_attack = 'There is no attack' # or anything else you want
        # both are same type
        if Pokemon2.types == k:
            string_1_attack = 'Its not very effective...'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python variables are scoped to the innermost function, class, or module in which they're assigned. You have to declare **string_1_attack** just before for loop like.

```
version = ['Fire', 'Water', 'Grass']
string_1_attack = None
for i, k in enumerate (version):
    if self.types == k:
```

For more information visit on this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)